# Providing subquery in query parameters

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto

I need to implement the following query with Ecto, however it doesn't compile saying the subquery statement is not a valid expression.

```
query = from p in Passphrase,
        left_join: pi in PassphraseInvalidation, on: p.id == pi.target_passphrase_id,
        join: u in User, on: p.user_id == u.id,
        where: p.passkey == ^passkey and
               is_nil(pi.inserted_at) and
               p.inserted_at > ago(5, "month") and
               p.inserted_at > subquery(from pr in PasswordReset,
                                        where: pr.user_id == u.id,
                                        select: max(pr.inserted_at)),
        select: {u, p}

user = Repo.one!(query)
```

> (Ecto.Query.CompileError) subquery(from(pr in PasswordReset, where: pr.user_id() == ^u.id(), select: max(pr.inserted_at()))) is not a valid query expression.

The equivalent PgSQL query would be something like:

```
SELECT u.*, p.*
FROM passphrases p
LEFT OUTER JOIN passphrase_invalidations pi ON p.id = pi.target_passphrase_id
INNER JOIN users u ON p.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.passkey = '/* some passkey */' AND
      pi.inserted_at IS NULL AND
      u.id = 2 AND
      p.inserted_at > (SELECT max(pr.inserted_at)
                       FROM password_resets pr
                       WHERE pr.user_id = u.id)
```

Is there a way to implement that, or am I missing something?

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#subquery/1 says "Subqueries are currently only supported in the `from` and `join` fields." so it looks like this isn't possible with subqueries right now.

Comment: @Dogbert what would be your suggestion about this, I need to supply type information in query. Could I use 'fragment/1' make this work?

Comment: How about `p.inserted_at > fragment("(SELECT max(pr.inserted_at) FROM password_resets pr WHERE pr.user_id = u.id)")`?

Comment: @Dogbert could you provide this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Ecto 2.1.0, according to https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#subquery/1, subqueries cannot be use in `where`:

> Subqueries are currently only supported in the `from` and `join` fields.

You can use `fragment` and put the entire subquery in it for now:

```
p.inserted_at > fragment("(SELECT max(pr.inserted_at) FROM password_resets pr WHERE pr.user_id = u.id)")
```

Answer (score 1):

`where` just became available (Ecto 3.4.3)

https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html#subquery/2